# Typescript and workspaces / monorepo

Tags: typescript, compilation, typechecking

We are trying to use monorepo approach (Yarn's workspaces) with Typescript.

We have, for example, two libraries: *@project/main* and *@project/common*.

*tsconfig.json* in each library looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "baseUrl": "./"
}
```

This allows us to use absolute imports in each library.

Now assume, that an *index.ts* in *@project/main* library contains:

```
import { foo } from "@project/common";
```

and *index.ts* in *@project/common contains*:

```
export * from "src/functions";
```

During the typecheck / compilation of *@project/main*, Typescript will try to find a *foo* function in *@project/main/src/functions.ts* instead of *@project/common/src/functions.ts*

This is because Typescript will correctly follow a "@project/common" import and then, it will try to follow "src/functions" export. However, this import is absolute, so Typescript will use a *baseUrl*, which heads to "@project/main".

To sole this issue, we can add something like this:

```
{
  "paths": {
    "*": [
      "*",
      "../../node_modules/@project/common/*"
    ]
  }
},
```

to *tsconfig.json* of a "@project/main" package.

This can solve our problem until we add a a *functions.ts* file to main project too (*@project/main/src/functions.ts*).

Now, Typescript will use a *functions.ts* from *@project/main* instead of a *@project/common*, which is obviously an unaccepted behaviour.

**So, my question is:** Is it possible to config a Typescript to use a *baseUrl* from a *tsconfig.json*, which is located alongside with a currently processed file or in its parent directory?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a relative path inside `@project/common`? `export * from "./src/functions";` should work.

Comment: I'm not using typescript but yarn workspaces with ecmascript, but this is a familiar issue. My rule of thumb is that within a package, all paths to its own modules must be relative (imports and exports) and should not rely on outside aliasing or symlinking. Absolute-style notation is only used when importing from other packages in the workspace.

Comment: I would advise not to use tsconfig paths with yarn workspaces, as workspaces already provide a clean way to refer dependencies, and tsconfig paths look like a hacky way.